# Ruby (on rails) check if a tree is not circular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of Questions. Every Question has i.e. 4 Answers and every Answer is linked to the next Question that has 4 Answers that are linked to the next Questions until the "Endquesion" without Answers.

This is a tree-like construct and I want to be certain that it stays that way - that no Answer linkes to a question that has already been asked.

I suppose the only way to do this would be with a recursive function.

I was thinking something like this:

mq = [question.id]
q= question.id

```
def not_circular(q, mq)
  mother_questions = mq
  sister_questions = []
  question = Question.find(q)
  question.answers.each do |a|
    if mother_questions.include?(a.next_question)
      return a.content
    else
      if !a.endlevel
        sister_questions << a.next_question
      end          
    end  
  end
  mother_questions = mother_questions + sister_questions

    question.answers.each do |a|
      if !a.endlevel
      return not_circular(a.next_question, mother_questions)
      end 
    end  
    return false
  end
```

But I see a few problems - I was thinking of making an array of the "Parent-Questions" and to check if the "next_question" is in this array (which would stop the function and return the "circular "next_question"). But in my example code there would be a false alarm with the "sister-next-questions" (when answers of the same Question point to the same next Question) that can and should be the same.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

Question has many Answers. Answer belongs to Questions. 
Answer has a :next_question variable pointing to the next question.

EDIT 2: 
I got the function to test at least one branch of the tree correctly (see new code above). Now I just have figure out how to make it test all branches.

Comment: Can you add your question and answer associations to your post please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions!

I actually managed to solve it my way (or at least my tests make it seem like I succeeded in solving it).

Here is my code:

```
mq = [Question.id]
q = Question.id

def not_circular(q, mq)
  if mq.empty?
   mother_questions = [q]
  else
   mother_questions = mq + [q]
  end  
  question = Question.find(q)
  question.answers.each do |a|
    if mother_questions.include?(a.next_question)
      return a.content
    else
      if a.next_question != 0 && !a.last_question
        if not_circular(a.next_question, mother_questions)
         return not_circular(a.next_question, mother_questions)
        end
      end          
    end  
  end      
  return false
end
```

Now the Answer that links to a previous question (thus making a circle) is returned to the Admin and he can change it.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of dealing with this problem in trees or even directed, acyclic graphs is with a validation on a join table. I'm not sure I completely understand the structure you're using, so I'll take a common problem of courses that are prerequisites to each other.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :prereqs, through: :course_relationships

  has_many :inverse_course_relationships, class_name: 'CourseRelationship', foreign_key: 'prereq_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :inverse_prereqs, through: :inverse_course_relationships, source: :course
end
```

Then I place a validation in a join table:

```
class CourseRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :prereq, class_name: 'Course'

  validate :is_acyclic

  def is_acyclic
    if course == prereq
      errors.add(:base, "A course can't be a prerequisite to itself")
      return false
    end

    check_for_course = Proc.new do |current_course|
      if course == current_course
        errors.add(:base, "Catch 22 detected. \"#{course.title}\" is already required before \"#{prereq.title}\".")
        return false
      end

      current_course.prereqs.each do |course_to_check|
        check_for_course.call course_to_check
      end
    end

    check_for_course.call prereq
    return true
  end
end
```

This ensures that every time a new relationship is created, a course will never be a prerequisite of itself (even if indirectly).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the responsibility (ie the validity) of this test should be on the answers, not the questions:  if someone links an answer to a question which has already been asked then it's the answer which is at fault, ie invalid, not the question which has been chosen.

So, i would move this test to the answer class thus: to make this work you need a new association in Question which points back to answers which have that question as the next question.  I haven't tested this but i think it should work.  Test that the `previous_answers` association works before trying the methods out.

```
#in Question
has_many :answers
has_many :previous_answers, :class_name => "Answer", :source => :next_question

#in Answer
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :next_question

validate :does_not_link_to_previously_asked_question

def does_not_link_to_previously_asked_question
  if self.previous_questions.include?(self.next_question)
    self.errors.add(:next_question_id, "This question has already been asked")
  end
end

def previous_questions
  current = [self.question]
  questions = []
  while current.size > 0
    current = current.collect(&:previous_answers).flatten.collect(&:question).reject(&:blank?)
    questions += current
  end
  questions.uniq
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't really want to do this in the model and link questions back to the answers. I would like this done in a method of a controller that checks if a quiz out of a set of Questions is possible without circles.

Answer (score 0):

There is some theory here that I haven't thought through fully, but if you want a simple guarantee that no circular paths can exist, the simplest way to achieve this is to ensure that no answer can be linked back to a question from a higher level than itself. So questions know where they are in the tree and answers cannot link above their question's level. Answers could still link to any question below their own level, just not above.

Otherwise I think you need to think about this calculation as a bit of stand-alone Ruby rather than trying to tie it too far into your model- you can create a fairly simple question and answer tree containing simply the Id and parent/child relationships to model the data without having to have too many conversations between layers. If it is in it's own module that will also make it way easier to test and manage.

The way to ensure you have cannot add questions that might lead to the current answer is to be certain that the questions that are available following from an answer do not exist on any path to that answer. If, in your tree model, each node is aware of it's parents as well as it's children, then this would be a fairly simple matter of walking the tree up from the current answer ( through each member of it's `parent` array ) and identifying every question on that path. Those questions then constitute an "excluded" list that cannot be legally added to the current answer.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer! I would really love to be able to do this, but do I have to save all parents of every question to be able to do this? What I am trying to do is create a custom validation that tells the user "change next_question of answer xy because it creates a circle"

Comment: That depends _where_ you perform this operation; you have to have a representation of the entire tree somewhere - there is no way you will ever be able to validate this without one no matter what approach you take - but as I am suggesting you take it out of the ActiveRecord model, you don't have to have saved it at all. When I mention an ID it could just be a guid or similar. In fact if you are interested in restricting user options, you could even implement the check in JavaScript on the client, which would potentially make it more responsive.